# How to write a function that returns an array of functions?

Tags: javascript

**Objective**

Write a function `values(f, low, high)` that yields an array of function values `[f(low), f(low + 1), . . ., f(high)`].

**What I Tried**

```js
function values(f, low, high) {
  var result = [];

  for(var i = low; i < high; i++) {
    result.push(j = f(i));
  }

  return result;
}

const vf = (p1) => console.log(p1);

const arrayOfFuns = values(vf, 10, 16);

console.log(arrayOfFuns);
console.log(arrayOfFuns[0]());
```

**Expected Output**

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
[ function, function, function, function, function, function ]
10 // console.log(arrayOfFuns[0]());
```

**Output**

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
/home/moss/var/Modern JS for the Impatient/3.3.js:16
console.log(arrayOfFuns[0]());
                          ^

TypeError: arrayOfFuns[0] is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/moss/var/Modern JS for the Impatient/3.3.js:16:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Why is the `arrayOfFuns` array element filled with `undefined`? I thought it would be an array of functions. Also I expected that accessing the first element of `arrayOfFuns` would print `10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

I have created a function named nf which returns the ith value and pushed it in the array.

```js
function values(f, low, high) {
  var result = [];

  for(let i = low; i < high; i++) {
    f(i);
    const nf = () => i;
    result.push(nf);
  }

  return result;
}

const vf = (p1) => console.log(p1);

const arrayOfFuns = values(vf, 10, 16);

console.log(arrayOfFuns);
console.log(arrayOfFuns[0]());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an anonymous function each time.

```js
function values(f, low, high) {
  var result = [];

  for(var i = low; i < high; i++) {
    result.push(()=> f(i));
  }

  return result;
}

const vf = (p1) => console.log(p1);

const arrayOfFuns = values(vf, 10, 16);

console.log(arrayOfFuns);
console.log(arrayOfFuns[0]());
```